# JIRA: how can I share modules between projects?

Tags: jira

My company started using JIRA for issue tracking two years ago, and we have struggled with optimizing the workflow for it since. The main problem is that we have a number of modules and libraries that are shared between different products, whereas JIRA has a "silo" view of projects. Basically, JIRA is fine for tracking issues from a "customer project" point of view, but I started to see it as more and more useless for a "back-end development" point of view.

JIRA's components are not good enough for my needs, since the developer of the module or library cannot correlate the issues appearing in different projects for her module and assign them to different versions of it. What I need is a hierarchy of projects, where a component in a higher (product) level project relates to another project at a lower (module) level.

Atlassian seems to be unwilling (unable?) to add such a feature to JIRA, despite numerous related issues dating back up to nine years. Moving to another issue tracking software that has this feature (if there exists any) is not feasible for us at the moment, though.

Judging from the number of replies on the related issues in Atlassian's JIRA system, we can't be the only company with this problem, so I would like to know what other people are doing to get around it.

My current plan is to use components for the product projects, and automatically create and link clones of component issues in the relevant module/library project. Clones are sub-optimal, since they are not as strongly linked to the original as I would like, and they double the number of issues in the system (or more, if the issue in the module project needs to be duplicated in other higher projects, say, if the fix would break the API or if it was a critical issue that any user of the library should be warned about), but I'd like to keep the original, since after fixing it in the module and closing the module issue, there'd be more time needed for integrating the fixed module into the product.

I have found plugins that allow post-functions on transitions, e.g. "CustomWare JIRA Utilities", so that should work for automated cloning, linking, and updating, although I am not 100% sure.

What is missing, though, is a good way to manage the dependencies between the different versions of products and modules (i.e., version X.Y of product A uses version I.J of library B), since versioned components are another thing that JIRA doesn't do.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would treat reusable components the same way they're treated for distribution (e.g. DLLs), as separate projects in Jira.

Track your issues against the affected version of the module. You can always move an issue between projects if it's discovered to be a different part.

This won't help maintain cross project mapping (I.e. System A v1.3 requires Component B v2.7) but it becomes simple enough to dump in a Wiki.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It confirms that I'm not completely off track with my setup (as currently planned). I would like to automate as much as possible, though, since I want to have the product projects as single point of entry for "top-down" issues (created by customers, for instance), so that they can then propagated to the right library project from there.

Comment: Perhaps using the ideas that you and @C4H5As have thrown out combine with project metadata (https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/42075) you could get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create your own multiselect custom field, make it valid across multiple JIRA projects and use that instead of the system components field. You would lose the ability to automatically assign issues but gain the ability to use "components" that are valid in more than one project.

~Matt

Answer (score 0):

OnTime uses a tree-based structure for projects, allowing you to open a filter to view descendents as if they were on the current branch. I don't know if that is much help for you.